# iOS invalid deviceToken

Tags: ios, objective-c, devicetoken

I'm trying to get iOS device token use code:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 10.0) {
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter          currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionBadge |       UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert |      UNAuthorizationOptionCarPlay) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *_Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"request authorization succeeded!");
        }
    }];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    #else
    UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |    UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
#endif
} else if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
    UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
} else {
    UIRemoteNotificationType apn_type = (UIRemoteNotificationType)    (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                                   UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                                                   UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:apn_type];
}
```

but i get device token `"bGb1GbbR17mB/XCWFpH+YpfyprlSvdy2ZN7aqF8QxHE="` in the **get token success callback  function**.

i use same code in another project can get right `device token`.
why? please help me!

Comment: yes , I'm still using Objective-C

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Note : Require to add push Notification Certificate in your Project

If you have add push Notification certificate than

Try This :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{

    self.AppDeviceToken=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
    //NSLog(@"My token is: %@", self.AppDeviceToken);

    self.AppDeviceToken = [self.AppDeviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    self.AppDeviceToken = [self.AppDeviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    self.AppDeviceToken = [self.AppDeviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"%@'s Device Token is : %@",[[UIDevice currentDevice] name],self.AppDeviceToken);
}
```

In iOS 10.0 or Greater

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(@"10.0"))
    {
        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        center.delegate = self;
        [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
            if(!error){
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
            }
        }];
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings: (UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);
    completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
    completionHandler();
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    self.AppDeviceToken=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
    //NSLog(@"My token is: %@", self.AppDeviceToken);

    self.AppDeviceToken = [self.AppDeviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    self.AppDeviceToken = [self.AppDeviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    self.AppDeviceToken = [self.AppDeviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"%@'s Device Token is : %@",[[UIDevice currentDevice] name],self.AppDeviceToken);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,i have try the code, but i get same invalid device token:ByT3fzJXUkKQ31+5B9UOBevFQITgqCX5QJ+CZZS8/KY=

Comment: You have use push notification Certificate ?

Comment: yes, in another project ,i use same bundle id, it is work fine

Comment: which OS on your Device?

Comment: thank you all, i have solution this question. my workmate create a category of NSData that change NSData's Description to base64 encode String.....

Comment: YOu can't convert NSData to NSString like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    if(CheckOSVersion >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

        UIUserNotificationSettings* currentSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
        UIUserNotificationType enabledTypes = currentSettings.types;

        BOOL turnedOffFromWithinNotificaitonCenter = ((enabledTypes & UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) == UIUserNotificationTypeAlert);

        if (turnedOffFromWithinNotificaitonCenter){
        }
        else{
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];

        if (types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]   registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    NSLog(@"Push Error- %@",[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err]);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSString *devToken = [[[[deviceToken description]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
    [AppDelegate instance].strToken = devToken;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"Push"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:devToken forKey:@"deviceToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    NSLog(@"Device Token of Device %@",devToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"Userinfo%@",userInfo);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your code ,but i still get invalid device token

Comment: thank you all, i have solution this question. my workmate create a category of NSData that change NSData's Description to base64 encode String.....